# Why elasticsearch gives incorrect results for sum aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to group all documents by user ID, calculate sum of `amountEUR` field, and return top 5 players with largest sum, and in other aggregation top 5 players with lowest sum.

`amountEUR` fields are floats (and they can be negative).

But when I run my code, there is something strange happening. Sometimes, specific user is included in both `top5Winners` and `top5Losers` with different values for each group.
How can that be possible?

How can user have sum `amountEUR` of `30000` in `top5Winners` and at the same time value of `-250000` in `top5Losers` group. That seems counter intuitive to me, can it be that elastic engine is not going trough all entries or something?

Also, when I put `size:10000`, I get completely different results for same dataset.

Am I doing something wrong or is this `normal` elasticsearch behaviour?

This is my query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [{ "exists": { "field": "amountEUR" } }]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top5Winners": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "playerid",
        "size": 5,
        "order": { "result": "desc" }
      },
      "aggs": { "result": { "sum": { "field": "amountEUR" } } }
    },
    "top5Losers": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "playerid",
        "size": 5,
        "order": { "result": "asc" }
      },
      "aggs": { "result": { "sum": { "field": "amountEUR" } } }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say `size:10000` you mean in the terms aggregation not the top level hits size, right? Can you confirm? And how many different users do you have approximately (i.e. cardinality of field `playerid`)?

Comment: But regardless, indeed, the way you're doing it cannot work like you expect. By aggregating on players, you're simply finding out the 5 most frequent players in your document set. Then, those 5 players are ranked according to the sum of the spending, which is why your finding the same player in both the winners and losers, but that is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Val Yes, when I say size: 10000, I mean in the terms aggregation, top level size is `0`

Comment: But that still leaves one important issue, sometimes I get different values for same user in both groups. `SUM` is done on same dataset and filter, how can it be that `top5Losers` and `top5Winners` have different value for specific user?

Comment: What about my earlier question: And how many different users do you have approximately (i.e. cardinality of field playerid)?

Comment: I have more than 10 million unique users. And this index that I am trying to search have around 100 documents per user per day.